# Wordpress - Is there an event triggered when settings fields are updated?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have various fields I have created using Settings API in Wordpress,

```
add_settings_field(
        'rpp_api_text_api2_host',
        __( 'API Host', 'wordpress' ),
        'rpp_api_text_api2_host_render',
        'rppPlugin',
        'rpp_api_rppPlugin_api2_section'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'rpp_api_text_api2_key',
        __( 'API Key', 'wordpress' ),
        'rpp_api_text_api2_key_render',
        'rppPlugin',
        'rpp_api_rppPlugin_api2_section'
    );
```

Now I need to run some specific code only when settings are saved, I can trigger it when any field is updated or if possible when a specific field is updated, it depends on the possibilities, any suggestion?

Comment: you can use callback function, try solution given here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89251/run-function-on-settings-save

Comment: @SangitaKendre the accepted answer is not that good, but the one below is just what I needed, thanks!!, can you add it as the answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is to add_action after an option as been updated.

See this answer: [Hook if somebody saves plugin options?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177272/hook-if-somebody-saves-plugin-options)